# Using awk or sed split pipe separated values into new lines keeping first string as common

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, sh

Below are my input and required output. How can I achieve this using sed or awk in unix? A single command or a pipe is fine.

**Input**

```
PRODUCT1,PRICEa|PRICEb|PRICEc
PRODUCT2,PRICEd
PRODUCT3,PRICEe|PRICEf
(and so on)
```

**Output**

```
PRODUCT1,PRICEa
PRODUCT1,PRICEb
PRODUCT1,PRICEc
PRODUCT2,PRICEd
PRODUCT3,PRICEe
PRODUCT3,PRICEf
(and so on)
```

Comment: You forgot to show your attempt in solving this.

Comment: in `awk` set FS to comma, split the second field by pipe symbol, loop through the elements and print first field and split array elements

Comment: Regarding my attempt, this is not the actual input. i have pipe before this which is getting the data from an XML file and formatting through some pipes till this input. But the remaining portion I am not able to do with sed. I am new to awk but i think it is achievable by awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\|/,ORS $1",")} 1'   Input_file
```

Comment: Wow, i think this is what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. It says I need to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer. I will definitely accept this.

Comment: @Cozimetzer, cheers :) keep learning and keep sharing, enjoy.

Comment: ++ for very good answer. `awk -F, '{gsub(/\|/,ORS $1 FS)} 1' file` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

bash

```
while IFS=',|' read -ra fields; do
    printf "${fields[0]},%s\n" "${fields[@]:1}"
done < file
```

Another awk

```
awk -F '[,|]' -v OFS=, '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1,$i}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^,]*,)(.*)\|(.*)/\1\2\n\1\3/;tA' infile
```